# Options for storing user information while logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What are some options in regards to maintaining user data while they are logged into my mvc4 site? I am building off of the Internet Application template and right now I am using `User.Identity.Name` to get the logged in user's username that they used to login with. I'd like to be able to also store and access several other pieces of information about the user across every page on the site. Can I still use `User.Identity` somehow and apply other attributes to it? I started building a `ProfileModel` that I could pass to views, but then I don't believe I would be able to pass other models to those views, not sure.

I'm open to suggestions as far as persistent user data, and thank you for any help.

EDIT 1: When I say persistent, I mean while they are logged in, the data itself is already stored in an external database, so I won't be doing any writing of this information, simply pulling it from the database, then holding onto it for the duration of them being logged in.

Comment: Storing this data in an encrypted cookie works pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to leverage `Session` for that. Consider the following code:

```
Session["Profile"] = profileObj;
```

or maybe you just want to store a string:

```
Session["SomeSetting"] = value;
```

What you need to store in `Session` is unclear, and effectively irrelevant, you can store anything. You can access the `Session` from any `Controller`.

Then later on you can get the value out like this:

```
var profile = Session["Profile"];

// if the profile variable is null then it doesn't exist in Session yet
```

In response to @AaronLS, `Session` lasts the duration of the IIS session that's created when the user first accesses the site. Do keep in mind that these sessions are reset if inactive for a period of time (I believe the default IIS timeout is 20 minutes) so you'd want to leverage the `null` return value to know that you need to redirect the user to the login page to login again.

Comment: You should clarify the lifetime of session data, and when that data is lost.  I would think the asker is looking for something more longterm given he's talking about "storing/persisting".

Comment: @AaronLS, fair enough. Done.

Comment: Perfect, I just tried this out and this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.